# android editable Baseurl Retrofit

Tags: android, api, retrofit

```
private static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.111.10:80/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;

    }
```

How can i make this base url dynamic(hostname value + protocole value + port value ) those value i have them in other activity and i like to use them in this class ApiClient

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your routes in this way:

```
@GET("{baseUrl}/...")
Call<ObjectDto> getCall(@Path(value = "baseUrl", encoded = true) String baseUrl, @Query("param") String param);
```

Then you can pass whatever you want

Edit: This will override the url used in Retrofit init

Code:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
Retrofit retrofit =
            new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://useless.it/").client(httpClient.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create()).build();

retrofitApi = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);
```

Comment: i like to do it in class apiclient because i have many call api

Comment: I had the same problem and after a lot of research this is the only solution I've found

Comment: can you show me code when you call this api how do you do that? beacuse i have erreur on .build() when i try to declares my routes like that

Comment: I've added the code on my answer, about baseUrl is a simple string. I remember that I had some strange issues but I can't remember what I had exactly, do you get some errors in console?

Comment: Also a dirty approach can be an interceptor, replacing base url for each request

Comment: Yes, but using dynamic baseUrl is a cleaner solution. Using interceptor you have to add a fake parameter to each call to understand which baseUrl you have to put on the request just created. Otherwise you have to map each call to the baseUrl to use